# I want to show that $\left | f(3)-P(3) \right |\leq \frac1{1000}$ without a calculator.

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, approximation

Let $f(x)=\ln x$. Then the Taylor polynomial of degree 2 at $x=e$ is $P(x)=1+\frac1e(x-e)-\frac1{2e^2}(x-e)^2$

I want to show that $\left | f(3)-P(3) \right |\leq \frac1{1000}$ without a calculator.
How can I show this?

Comment: Do you know Taylor's formula for the error term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the next term of the Taylor series to be $\frac {(3-e)^3}{3e^3},$ which you are ignoring.  The alternating series theorem says your error is less than this.  Now estimate $3-e \lt 0.3$ and convince yourself that $e^3 \gt 10$ and you will be there.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the error of a taylor polynomial, is at most the (absolute) value of the next term, so when you have an expansion in $x=a$, you get
$$
f(x)\sim f_2(x) =f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac 1{2!} f''(a)(x-a)^2
$$
and the error of it is at most
$$
|f(x)-f_2(x)|\leq \left|\frac 1{3!}f^{(3)}(c)(x-a)^3\right|
$$
where $c$ is some value between $a$ and $x$.

Comment: This is false. According to your claim $|\cos x - (1 -\frac{1}{2}x^2)| \leq 0$.

Comment: I was missing the absolute value on the right side. Is that what you meant?

Comment: No. According to what you've written, any function $f$ with $f^{(3)}(a) = 0$ satisfies $f(x) = f_2(x)$. You need to check your formula as it is incorrect.

Comment: Ah, i see the problem. lets solve it...

Answer (score 0):

The [Lagrange form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder)  of the remainder $R_k(x) = f(x) - P_k(x)$ of the k-th order Taylor polynomial is given by $R_k(x) = \frac{f^{(k+1)}(\xi_L)}{(k+1)!} (x-a)^{k+1}, $ where $\xi_L$ lies between $a$ and $x.$